# Proper Error throwing for function argument validation

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, runtime-error, throw

I have the following type of function definition:

```
const myModule = function (value1) {

  // Is value1 missing?
  if (typeof(value1) === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('value1 is missing')
  }

  // Do stuff here

}
```

There is a required `value1` parameter/argument that needs to be passed into the function. If it's missing, then I need to throw an error. Am I throwing the error correctly? When I run this, I get this type of output in the console:

```
/Users/me/script.js:10
    throw new Error('value1 is missing')
    ^

Error: value1 is missing
    at new myModule (/Users/me/script.js:10:11)
```

Is this the proper way to do this? It seems weird that it outputs the actual `throw` statement into the console.

Comment: it is working for you ?

Comment: Well yes, it works. I'm just not sure if that is the best practice for how to throw errors or if that is the common way to do it. Thanks,

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: I misunderstood. No, the answer provided only discusses how to handle an error. I'm asking what the proper way is to throw an error. Maybe I'm already doing in correctly. I don't know.

Comment: @Yes, you used corectly.Another method is to throw error simply using only the message:`throw 'value1 is missing'`. My answer tell you how to handle this types of errors.

Comment: But throwing an Error will result in a proper stack trace and just a message won't, right?

Comment: When you use `throw new Error`, it returns an object which have `name` and `message`, like in my answer. If you use only `throw message`, then it returns a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using the **[`throw`statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)** is the proper way to throw errors in `JavaScript`. But you can use the [**Console**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) built-in methods, it will allow you to throw different types of errors.

If you have different types of messages/errors/Exceptions to throw you can profit from the [**Console**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) **[methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Methods)**:

> `Console.error()`
>
> Outputs an error message. You may use string substitution and
>   additional arguments with this method.
>
> `Console.info()`
>
> Informative logging information. You may use string
>   substitution and additional arguments with this method.
>
> `Console.log()`
>
> For general output of logging information. You may use string
>   substitution and additional arguments with this method.
>
> `Console.trace()`
>
> Outputs a stack trace warning message. You may use string substitution and additional arguments with this method.
>
> `Console.warn()`
>
> Outputs a warning message. You may use string substitution and additional arguments with this method.

**Demo:**

This is a simple Demo showing the use of these methods:

```js
const myModule = function(value1) {

  // Is value1 missing?
  if (!value1) {
    console.error('value1 is missing!!!');
  //Is value a string?
  } else if (typeof value !== "string") {
    console.warn('value1 must be a string!!!');
  }
  // Do stuff here

}
```

Comment: But a `console.error()` for example doesn't halt the execution of the program. Halting execution would be desirable if the developer isn't using the module correctly.

Comment: Yes `console.log()` won't halt the execution of the code, In that case you will need to use the `throw` statement. But `throw` can also break the execution of the remaining code. Say if you have some other treatment after it, what would you do in that case